# Horizontal scroll bar issue when using rtl style with TreeView

Tags: asp.net, css, right-to-left

The problem is that the website is very wide. A horizontal scroll bar is added and the width of the page becomes like 10000. The problem happens once I use treeview if the page style is RTL.

If I change the page to LTR or if I remove the treeview, the problem disappears.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

set this property for treeview

```
SkipLinkText=""

<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" SkipLinkText="">
</asp:TreeView>
```